# Lower bound for the Schwartz–Zippel lemma in Polynomial Hashing

Tags: polynomials, hash-function

$\newcommand{\bigparen}[1]{\Bigl ( #1 \Bigr )}$

I'm working with polynomial hashes $H$ defined by the pair $(B, M)$ (base, modulo):

$$H_{B, M}(s) \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B^{n-1-i} \cdot conv(s_i) \, (mod \, M)$$

The conversion function is `conv(c) = c - 'a' + 1` (work only with lowercase letters). I work with strings of different lengths.

The scheme I use to guarantee a small enough collision probability takes a fixed modulo (in this case the largest Mersenne prime that fits in $8$ bytes, $2^{61} - 1$), and chooses one uniformly random base from the set $\{26 + 1, ..., 2 ^ {61} - 2\}$.

The probability for any two different strings $s$, $t$:

$$P\bigparen{H(s) \equiv H(t) \, (mod \, M)} = P\bigparen{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B^{n-1-i} \cdot (conv(s_i) - conv(t_i)) \equiv 0 \, (mod \, M)} \leq \frac{n-1}{M}$$

Since the left side is a $n-1$-degree polynomial in a randomly chosen variable, the base $B$ (Schwartz–Zippel lemma).

At one point in my algorithm I'm sorting $n \log_2 n$ hashes, so an upper bound for the probability of collision would be:

$$1 - \bigparen{1 - \frac{n - 1}{M}} ^ {\lceil n \log_2 n \rceil \choose 2}$$

That is too high (for $n = 10^5$ it's $22\%$). In order to get a good bound with this scheme, I need to randomly pick two distinct bases. I'd rather not do this because of the noticeable slowdown in memory access times.

However, in practice, I would expect the probability that two hashes would collide to be much closer to $\frac{1}{M}$ (uniform spread over the codomain) than $\frac{n-1}{M}$.

Supposing that I can pick $B$ such that $B^i \not\equiv B^j \, (mod \, M) \,\, \forall \,\, 0 \leq i \lt j \lt n$, could there be a better upper bound out there for the probability of the hashes ($H_{B, M}, B$ chosen randomly, $M$ fixed and prime) of any two strings colliding than $\frac{n-1}{M}$? Maybe some other initial conditions could help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a pragmatic approach would be to use a [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) (see also [here](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2023/05/08/prfs-prps-and-other-fantastic-things/)) instead of a polynomial hash, because then you can say that the collision probability is $1/M$ (unless someone figures out how to break the crypto).  Or, alternatively, to use a 128-bit hash rather than a 64-bit hash; maybe [Poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305).

I wouldn't set your hopes too high on proving a better bound.  My intuition is that the collision probability is probably more like $(n-1)/M$, not $1/M$, as a random polynomial of degree $n-1$ has on average about $n-1$ unique roots modulo $M$.  Note that the hashes can still be uniformly distributed across the codomain: it is the difference between the probability distribution with respect to a random choice of $B$, vs the probability distribution with respect to a random choice of input string.